# Prime numbers between two multiples of numbers

Tags: number-theory

I am wondering about the following question.

> Do there exist infinitely many prime numbers $p$ such that there exist integers $m,n$ with $5(m+1) \geq 7n$ and $$5m < p < 7n?$$

If not, what other numbers would we have to replace $5$ and $7$ by for there to be? If so, what is the minimal set of numbers we would have to replace $5$ and $7$ by? This leads onto my second question below.

> Find numbers $a,b$ with $|a-b|$ minimal such that there exist infinitely many primes $p$ with the property that there exist integers $m,n$ with $a(m+1) \geq bn$ and $$am < p < bn.$$

Comment: Where is $n$  involved?

Comment: @Bernard Thanks, that was a typo.

Comment: The standard Dirichlet result gives infinitely many primes $p$ of the form $35n-1$. For such primes we have $5(7n-1)<p<7\cdot5n=5\cdot7n$

Comment: @almagest:  that should be an answer.  I was thinking down that line.

Comment: @RossMillikan then your welcome to put it up. I am too busy on something else to think about the second part of the question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Following almagest: The standard Dirichlet result gives infinitely many primes pp of the form $35n−1$. For such primes we have $5(7n−1)\lt p\lt 7⋅5n$

The same argument works with $a=6, b=7,$ primes of the form $42n-1$

Comment: What is the standard Dirichlet result?

Comment: Any arithmetic progression $a+kd$ where $a,d$ are coprime and $k \in \Bbb N$ contains an infinite number of primes.  Here in [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet%27s_theorem_on_arithmetic_progressions)  @SubhadeepDey because I stole almagest's comment for the answer by his request